# How to get USA states programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am developing an iphone application in Objective-C. 
I have to get the list of the states of USA programmatically. How can I get that list?

Answer (score 10):

I would hard-code the list in the source code. It's likely not to change during the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 2):

You could download it from wikipedia or some other source. I don't think there's anything built-in into the iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 0):

use this json

```
[
{
    "name": "Alabama",
    "abbreviation": "AL"
},
{
    "name": "Alaska",
    "abbreviation": "AK"
},
{
    "name": "American Samoa",
    "abbreviation": "AS"
},
{
    "name": "Arizona",
    "abbreviation": "AZ"
},
{
    "name": "Arkansas",
    "abbreviation": "AR"
},
{
    "name": "California",
    "abbreviation": "CA"
},
{
    "name": "Colorado",
    "abbreviation": "CO"
},
{
    "name": "Connecticut",
    "abbreviation": "CT"
},
{
    "name": "Delaware",
    "abbreviation": "DE"
},
{
    "name": "District Of Columbia",
    "abbreviation": "DC"
},
{
    "name": "Federated States Of Micronesia",
    "abbreviation": "FM"
},
{
    "name": "Florida",
    "abbreviation": "FL"
},
{
    "name": "Georgia",
    "abbreviation": "GA"
},
{
    "name": "Guam",
    "abbreviation": "GU"
},
{
    "name": "Hawaii",
    "abbreviation": "HI"
},
{
    "name": "Idaho",
    "abbreviation": "ID"
},
{
    "name": "Illinois",
    "abbreviation": "IL"
},
{
    "name": "Indiana",
    "abbreviation": "IN"
},
{
    "name": "Iowa",
    "abbreviation": "IA"
},
{
    "name": "Kansas",
    "abbreviation": "KS"
},
{
    "name": "Kentucky",
    "abbreviation": "KY"
},
{
    "name": "Louisiana",
    "abbreviation": "LA"
},
{
    "name": "Maine",
    "abbreviation": "ME"
},
{
    "name": "Marshall Islands",
    "abbreviation": "MH"
},
{
    "name": "Maryland",
    "abbreviation": "MD"
},
{
    "name": "Massachusetts",
    "abbreviation": "MA"
},
{
    "name": "Michigan",
    "abbreviation": "MI"
},
{
    "name": "Minnesota",
    "abbreviation": "MN"
},
{
    "name": "Mississippi",
    "abbreviation": "MS"
},
{
    "name": "Missouri",
    "abbreviation": "MO"
},
{
    "name": "Montana",
    "abbreviation": "MT"
},
{
    "name": "Nebraska",
    "abbreviation": "NE"
},
{
    "name": "Nevada",
    "abbreviation": "NV"
},
{
    "name": "New Hampshire",
    "abbreviation": "NH"
},
{
    "name": "New Jersey",
    "abbreviation": "NJ"
},
{
    "name": "New Mexico",
    "abbreviation": "NM"
},
{
    "name": "New York",
    "abbreviation": "NY"
},
{
    "name": "North Carolina",
    "abbreviation": "NC"
},
{
    "name": "North Dakota",
    "abbreviation": "ND"
},
{
    "name": "Northern Mariana Islands",
    "abbreviation": "MP"
},
{
    "name": "Ohio",
    "abbreviation": "OH"
},
{
    "name": "Oklahoma",
    "abbreviation": "OK"
},
{
    "name": "Oregon",
    "abbreviation": "OR"
},
{
    "name": "Palau",
    "abbreviation": "PW"
},
{
    "name": "Pennsylvania",
    "abbreviation": "PA"
},
{
    "name": "Puerto Rico",
    "abbreviation": "PR"
},
{
    "name": "Rhode Island",
    "abbreviation": "RI"
},
{
    "name": "South Carolina",
    "abbreviation": "SC"
},
{
    "name": "South Dakota",
    "abbreviation": "SD"
},
{
    "name": "Tennessee",
    "abbreviation": "TN"
},
{
    "name": "Texas",
    "abbreviation": "TX"
},
{
    "name": "Utah",
    "abbreviation": "UT"
},
{
    "name": "Vermont",
    "abbreviation": "VT"
},
{
    "name": "Virgin Islands",
    "abbreviation": "VI"
},
{
    "name": "Virginia",
    "abbreviation": "VA"
},
{
    "name": "Washington",
    "abbreviation": "WA"
},
{
    "name": "West Virginia",
    "abbreviation": "WV"
},
{
    "name": "Wisconsin",
    "abbreviation": "WI"
},
{
    "name": "Wyoming",
    "abbreviation": "WY"
}
]
```